# Calling javascript from codebehind not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Message() {
        swal("Registration Completed!", "An email will be sent once your access has been accepted.", "success");
    }
</script>

 // Call javascript function
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "", "Message()", true);
```

The function is not being called. This is my first time doing this and I don't know entirely how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String strScript = "window.onload = function() { Message();};";

 // Call javascript function
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Message", strScript, true);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more like to attract upvotes.